# YII separate log files to store messages category-wise

Tags: php, logging, yii

I want to store my log message in separate log file instead default /protected/runtime/application.log file.

my config/main.php file is like

```
'log'=>array(
            'class'=>'CLogRouter',
            'routes'=>array(
                array(
                    'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                    'levels'=>'error, warning,info,trace',
                    'categories'=>'system.*',
                ),
```

and my log message function is used here

```
public function changeLanguage($localLanguage)
{

    $currentLanguage=yii::app()->language;
    yii::app()->language=$localLanguage;
    $message='langusge changed from '.$currentLanguage.' to '.$localLanguage;
    $level='info';
    $category='system.web.CController';
    Yii::log($message, $level, $category);
}
```

This log message gets stored in application.log along with lots of messages other then mine.
So I want separate file for my change language function log.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to define an additional log route, specifying a different [log file name](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CFileLogRoute#logFile-detail):

```
'log'=>array(
    'class'=>'CLogRouter',
    'routes'=>array(
        array(
            'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
            'categories'=>'system.*',
        ),
        array(
            'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
            'logFile'=>'custom.log',
            'categories'=>'custom.*',
        ),
    )
)
```

More details can be found in the [logging](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.logging) section of the definitive guide.

Comment: It worked.Thanks for suck a quick response.

Comment: use the new logs with: Yii::log("hello", "info", "custom");

Comment: Hi, I want to create separate log file for each module in my project. Can anybody help me for the same?